# Google calendar - Insert events from azure not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a requirement where I need to update a user's google calendar when an event is inserted in the application's fullcalendar. I am using the peleyal's example for ASP.Net MVC and OAuth for Google API (using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow and AuthorizationCodeMvcApp) to handle this. I believe I have set up the credentials right in the google developer console as well.

I am able to create events on the google calendar locally without a problem. But from the azure deployed site I am not able to create the event. There are no exceptions/errors either. **Is there anything that needs to be done from azure side to be able to create events and to use Google API?**

```
  var finalREsult = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetaData()).AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);


                if (result.Credential != null)
                {
                    var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                        ApplicationName = "****"
                    });

                    var startDate = patientappointment.DateScheduled.Value.ToUniversalTime();
                    var endDate = patientappointment.DateScheduled.Value.AddMinutes(patientappointment.AppointmentLengthMinutes).ToUniversalTime();
                    var myEvent = new Event
                    {
                        Summary = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} - {3}", patientappointment.CurrentUserName, patientappointment.LocationName, patientappointment.RoomName, patientappointment.Notes),
                        Location = "Ireland",
                        Start = new EventDateTime
                        {
                            DateTime = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day, startDate.Hour, startDate.Minute, 0),
                            TimeZone = "(GMT+01:00) Dublin"
                        },
                        End = new EventDateTime
                        {
                            DateTime = new DateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, endDate.Day, endDate.Hour, endDate.Minute, 0),
                            TimeZone = "(GMT+01:00) Dublin"
                        },
                        Recurrence = new String[] { "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO" }
                        // Attendees = new List<EventAttendee> { new EventAttendee { Email = "**0@gmail.com" } },
                    };

                    EventsResource.InsertRequest request = service.Events.Insert(myEvent, "******@group.calendar.google.com");
                    request.Execute();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Looking at the requests information, I dont see the request being sent to first autheticate and get the auth code from the deployed site.

```
internal class ForceOfflineGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow : GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
{
public   ForceOfflineGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
(AuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer initializer)
    : base((GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer)initializer) { }

public override AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(string redirectUri)
{
    return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(new Uri(AuthorizationServerUrl))
    {
        ResponseType = "code",
        ClientId = ClientSecrets.ClientId,
        Scope = string.Join(" ", Scopes),
        RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        AccessType = "offline",
        ApprovalPrompt = "force",
        State = ""
    };
}
};

public class AppFlowMetaData : FlowMetadata
{
private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new ForceOfflineGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
        ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"]
    },
    Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
    DataStore = null
});

public override string GetUserId(System.Web.Mvc.Controller controller)
{
    return "user1";
}

public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
{
    get { return flow; }
}
}
```

Comment: can you post the cod for  AuthorizationCodeMvcApp?   and what type of azure server is it?

Comment: you might want to look though this.   https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/blob/f602557455dc8a6a89ebe3e36ceb4306a36dd5c3/Calendar.ASP.NET.MVC5/Controllers/CalendarController.cs    I am not sure how you are saving the authentication but I have wondered weather a free azure web server gives you access to write to %appdata% which is where filedatastore stores its data.

Comment: @DaImTo : I am using the default implementation of  AuthorizationCodeMvcApp available in the [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.1/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1Mvc_1_1AuthorizationCodeMvcApp). I dont use a free azure web server since I have credit and also have a custom domain name. Can we do without accessing the appdata? I am getting the auth code and token every time and not saving it in appdata(or anywhere). Strangely, this works in the localhost but not in the azure-deployed. I have made the url parameter , ApprovalPrompt = "force".

Comment: @DaImTo : I have added the class that I have overriden for customizing it to the original piece of code. Pls chk. Thanks,

Comment: If memory services if you don't supply a datastore the client lib will by default use filedatastore.  so it probably is trying to save to %appdata%.    You added the redirect uri for the azure server to developer console right?

Comment: @DaImTo : Probably not setting DataStore at all would work?

Comment: No because by default the clientlibrary itself just uses filedatastore if you don't send something else.

Comment: contact me http://www.daimto.com/contact/

Comment: @DaImTo:  sent mail . thanks